# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Note6MVCApplication5.Models.SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult' to 'Note6MVCApplication5.Models.Emp'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            Emp emp = db.SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoin(id).SingleOrDefault();
            ViewData["DeptId"] = new SelectList(db.SPGetAllDeptDetails().ToList(), "DeptId", "DeptName", emp.DeptId);
            return View(emp);
        }
```

> Error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'Note6MVCApplication5.Models.SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult' to 'Note6MVCApplication5.Models.Emp'

Why this error is coming?

> I am posting definition of SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult() which is present in MVCDemoDB.Designer.cs

```
public partial class SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult
    {

        private int _EmpId;

        private string _EmpName;

        private string _EmpJob;

        private decimal _EmpSalary;

        private int _DeptId;

        private string _DeptName;

        public SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult()
        {
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_EmpId", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
        public int EmpId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EmpId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._EmpId != value))
                {
                    this._EmpId = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_EmpName", DbType="VarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string EmpName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EmpName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._EmpName != value))
                {
                    this._EmpName = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_EmpJob", DbType="VarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string EmpJob
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EmpJob;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._EmpJob != value))
                {
                    this._EmpJob = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_EmpSalary", DbType="Money NOT NULL")]
        public decimal EmpSalary
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EmpSalary;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._EmpSalary != value))
                {
                    this._EmpSalary = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_DeptId", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
        public int DeptId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DeptId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._DeptId != value))
                {
                    this._DeptId = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_DeptName", DbType="VarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string DeptName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DeptName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._DeptName != value))
                {
                    this._DeptName = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to follow the instructions for posting questions.

Comment: `db.SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoin` returns `SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult` and not `Emp`. Take a look at the definition of `SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult` (which seems to be a custom class of yours) to see how you can extract the `Emp` from it. Maybe you want to use the debugger. To enable us to help you further, you should show the definition of `SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult`.

Comment: Please, see my improved question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Type Cast Error.  i would suggest declare variable of type 'var' instead of Emp in below statement

```
 Emp emp = db.SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoin(id).SingleOrDefault();
```

to something like this

```
 var emp = db.SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoin(id).SingleOrDefault();
```

second approach

Define extension method to cast SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult to Emp some thing like below 
sample Emp class

```
    public class Emp
    {
        public int DeptId { get; set; }

        public int EmpId { get; set; }

        /*
         * define other properties
         */
    }

    public static Emp ToEmp(this SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoinResult empResult)
    {
        return new Emp() {EmpId = empResult.EmpId, DeptId = empResult.DeptId};
    }
```

and  call the extension method

```
Emp emp = db.SPGetEmpDetailsByEmpIdJoin(id).SingleOrDefault().ToEmp();
```

that would fix your issue. hope this helps :)